# MYSQL using Google App Engine GWT

Tags: gwt, google-apps-script

Is it possible to connect to external MYSQL using Google App Engine GWT ? Can you share an example ?

Comment: Can we connect GWT to Cloud SQL ?

Comment: Normaly it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible possible to connect an external mySql database in a GWT project using JPA with GWT RequestFactory to handle client-server communication for instance.

Here is a tutorial for RequestFactory:
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html

And about JPA, there is nothing special about it, just import the right libs and use it normally.

Regards